# Explanation of Probability Solution

Tags: probability

[image]

I understand where the denominator, $12^{12}$ came from as there are $12$ students who can roll one of $12$ different numbers and in part (b) there are $11$ students who can roll one of $11$ different numbers. What I am trying to understand is where the numerators came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a student not to roll a match, he needs to roll one of the other $11$ numbers. So the probability one of $12$ students rolls a number different from his own is $\frac{11}{12}$.

Hence the probability all $12$ students roll a number different from there own as

$$\frac{11^{12}}{12^{12}}$$

And the probability at least $1$ rolls their own number is then

$$1-\frac{11^{12}}{12^{12}}$$

Similarly for question (b)

Comment: so basically if this were in forms of steps..step 1 would be to choose the number to be excluded..leaving $11$ numbers remaining to choose from?

Comment: Yes. Because each student has exactly one number he can't roll (in order for it not to be a match) leaving 11 he can roll